# Locked out of GSuite Admin after domain verification

Tags: google-workspace

I have signed up for Gsuite Essentials and attempted up upgrade to Gsuite Enterprise. I only have a single email address eg a@abc.com. I had already been using this account as a normal google account. (no gmail though).

I couldn't get the admin console to show the upgrade option, but found I needed to verify my domain. So I added the TXT record to my domain abc.com, which would then let me verify.

I could then log in to the admin console as a@abc.com and clicked on the upgrade option and completed the process. This then let my a@abc.com user have access to Gmail. I have not transferred any domain settings over to google, that is all still externally hosted.

I can now no longer log in to the admin console, it says that my a@abc.com account doesn't have the rights and I need to log in as the administrator. There is no other account linked to the Gsuite settings, so there is no other administrator. I can still log in to the normal google account and do the same functions as previous.

I have now removed the TXT record hoping that would cancel it out again.

How do I get access to the admin side again?

Side note: What I am mostly worried about is that I put my credit card details into the signup, but can't get into the admin page and can't contact any form of support. It is literally impossible to get support to use the serve I paid for.

Comment: Would this question be better asked on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, the txt records are a string for the only purpose to verify the ownership of the domain therefore deleting them won't change anything you only need this record for the verification process and once is done you can delete them.
As an example is like a text message sent to your mobile phone, if you delete the message nothing will happen right?

I tell you this so you won't more time on the domain DNS zone settings because the issue is not there and you won't solve the problem.

There may be few things that may have happened.

The first thing you should do is to navigate in an [Incognito page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), make sure that is the only incognito page that you have opened and log in with a@abc.com.

Try to run different test in incognito, the issue really looks like that you are logged in with multiple Google Accounts and when you go do admin.google.com it picks up the wrong one. That's why you should go in incognito.

---

> > > EDIT

Use as reference this link [Here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9122284).

Follow the steps in Paragraph 'I'm taking control from another admin' here the steps:

1. Go to the  [G Suite Essentials sign-up page](https://gsuite.google.com/signup/essentials/welcome).
   2, Sign up using your email address at the domain you're verifying.
   Use an address where you can get mail.
2. Follow instructions in the Setup Wizard to become the admin who manages G Suite Essentials for all users at your organization.

---

If this didn't solve the issue then you should contact the Google Support and they will tell you what happened.

The thing is that if you can't access the Google Admin you won't be able to contact the Google Support, hence you should follow this:

.1 Can't sign in to the Admin console: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6335621?hl=en

Comment: I tried incognito mode, and still got the same "admin.google.com is used for G Suite accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com. Learn More". I also browse cookieless anyway, so this shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: The support page is very circular... It says to log in with the admin account, or add one, but it's the only account. And the choices on the lost password section don't apply because they still would only unlock that same account. And correct, I can't contact any form of support.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are login in with the email address that you created the G Suite essential account ?

Comment: Darren I edidt my answer, check it out and see if this solves the issue.   Also if what I edit still don't solve the issue, I may think that maybe you did not create the account for real, so try to repeat the sign up process?